# Interactives <select>

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Thank you very much for your clear and fast answer.

Maybe I have to precise: it's in a wordpress website. The part with the FIRST select is in  a PHP CODE WIDGET and the second select is in the subtag.php page i have uploaded in the website!

On my page I inserted it (it's write in French sometimes):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#constructeur_moto_id").change(function(){
        $("#subcat").load("subtag.php?name="+$("#constructeur_moto_id").val());
    });
});
</script>
Constructeur Moto
<select name="constructeur_moto_id" id="constructeur_moto_id">
<?php
//Select Moto Brand
$constructeur = 'SELECT constructeur_moto_id,constructeur_moto_nom FROM a_constructeur_moto ORDER BY constructeur_moto_nom';
$constructeur_query = mysql_query($constructeur) or die( 'Erreur' );
    echo '<option>Constructeur Moto</option>';
    while ( $constructeur_list = mysql_fetch_array( $constructeur_query ) ) {
        echo '<option value="'.$constructeur_list['constructeur_moto_id'].'">'.$constructeur_list['constructeur_moto_nom'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<div id="subcat"></div>
```

The list of moto brand (constructeur_moto) appears like I want on my page.

Here is my subtag.php page:

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['name']))
{ 
echo $_REQUEST['name'];
?>
Modele Moto
<select name="modele_moto_nom">
<?php
//Select Modele moto
$modele = 'SELECT modele_moto_id,modele_moto_nom,modele_moto_annee,modele_constructeur_moto_id FROM a_modele_moto WHERE  modele_constructeur_moto_id='.$_REQUEST['name'].' ORDER BY modele_moto_nom';
$modele_query = mysql_query($modele) or die( 'Erreur' );
    echo '<option>Modèle Moto</option>';
    while ( $modele_list = mysql_fetch_array( $modele_query ) ) {
        echo '<option value="'.$modele_list['modele_moto_id'].'">'.$modele_list['modele_moto_nom'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

When I choose a moto brand, the subtag.php page is loaded (I echo the moto brand ID to check this (line 3)), the < select > form appears but nothing is loaded in it. I really don't undestand!

Comment: You have to listen `onchange` event on the 1st select and do AJAX request whenever it trigger

Comment: You might want to do `die (mysql_errnum() . ' -- ' . mysql_error())` instead of just `die ('error')`.  Also the mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed in the future.  They're not maintained and will only cause you grief in the long term.  Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Hello hindmost, what do you mean by "listening" the onchange event?

Answer (score 0):

i have created solution for you..
first you need to include jquery on your page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

after placing this script on your page you have to write jquery which will pass the data for your sub tag which is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#moto_brand_nom").change(function(){
        $("#subcat").load("subtag.php?name="+$("#moto_brand_nom").val());
    });
});
</script>
```

after placing the script you need to write your `<select>` tag with passing id as i have done.

```
<select name="moto_brand_nom" id="moto_brand_nom">
<?php
//Select Moto Brand
$constructeur = 'SELECT moto_brand_id,moto_brand_name FROM a_constructeur_moto ORDER BY moto_brand_name';
$constructeur_query = mysql_query($constructeur) or die( 'Erreur' );
    echo '<option>Moto Brand</option>';
    while ( $constructeur_list = mysql_fetch_array( $constructeur_query ) ) {
        echo '<option value="'.$constructeur_list['moto_brand_id'].'">'.$constructeur_list['moto_brand_name'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

then you have to write just a `<div>` tag with passing its id

```
 <div id="subcat"></div>
```

after this process you have to create one another page called subtag.php and place the code of below on the page.

```
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['name']))
{ ?>
<select name="model_moto_name">
<?php
//Select Model moto
$model = 'SELECT model_moto_id,model_moto_name,model_moto_annee,constructeur_moto_name FROM a_model_moto WHERE  moto_brand_id='.$_REQUEST['name'].' ORDER BY model_moto_name';
$model_query = mysql_query($model) or die( 'Erreur' );
    echo '<option>model Moto</option>';
    while ( $model_list = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
        echo '<option value="'.$model_list['model_moto_id'].'">'.$model_list['model_moto_name'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<?php } ?>
```

i hope this code will work for you

Comment: Thx Prateik, as I'm new I can't answer for 8 hours. I'll come back later to explain the problems I still have! Thanks again!

Comment: Hello Prateik! I have edited my question so if you can take a look at it! Thx!

Comment: you have to check for id which is passed from first select called moto_brand_nom, if id will not passed properly then only you will get blank <select> otherwise you will get the value in <select> if id passed properly.

Comment: you just write a page name in your page with passing "name=id" which is in the database. for example if page name is category.php and database id is 5, then u just write category.php?name=5 and you will get the ans for sure..

Comment: In my subtag.php page, I putted echo $_REQUEST['name']; and the echo of this is the moto_brand_id I've selected. So I've the good one.
The problem is that my code for the select are on a "widget" on my wordpress site and I'm asking myself if the script is working putting in it like that. I really don't undestand!

Comment: i also dont know bt you can try for that code if it is works then fine, because i have tested this code in core i dont know if it works in widget or not..